# uv mapping opposite way

Tags: mesh, uv, uv-image-editor

hey all so I have a normal texture written a name on it 'MARIA* when I UV project from view , the texture on the mesh is fine but the letters are the opposite way as you can see in the picture? how can I make letters as normal ? thanks In Advance [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *UV Editor*, select the UV faces that display the logo and reverse them (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd>).